# Grothendieck Riemann Roch, universal bundle on $SU_C(2,L)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I've problems with the use of Grothendieck Riemann Roch Theorem. 
Let $U$ be the the universal bundle on the moduli space $n:=SU_C(2,L)$, $C$  a smooth projective curve of genus $g$ and $L$ a line bundle of odd degree $d$.
I'd like to understand why, if a name $\pi: N:=SU_C(2,L) \times C \to SU_C(2,L)$ the projection, then I have 
$$c_1(\pi_*(U))= -\omega+(d+2-2g)\phi,$$ 
where $\omega$ and $\phi$ are such as:
$$c_2(U)= \eta \otimes \omega + \psi + 1 \otimes \chi$$
($\omega \in H^2(N), \psi \in H^0(N) \otimes H^1(C), \chi \in H^4(N)$).
Futhemore, we know that 
$$c_1(U) = c_1(L) \otimes 1+ 1 \otimes \phi$$
where $\phi=c_1(\Phi) \in H^2(N)$ with $\Phi$ a certain line bundle.
I can't deduce it from GRR because I don't know how to compute $ch(R^1 \pi_* U)$

Comment: Is your question (1) how does one show $c_1(U) = c_q(L) \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes \phi$, (2) how does one compute $\text{ch}(R^1\pi_*U)$, or (3) can one use GRR to deduce the known expression $c_1(U) = c_1(L) \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes \phi$? Or perhaps all three? (Sorry if this is obvious to someone who knows more of what's going on.)

Comment: The question is how to prove that $c_1(\pi_*(U))=-\omega+(d+2-2g)\phi$ knowing that for $c_1(U)$ and $c_2(U)$ there are those decomposition.

Comment: What I mean is that I know the GRR theorem in the following version: given a vector bundle $E$, $C$ a curve of genus $g$ on $C \times Y$ and $f: C \times Y \to Y$, then $$ch(f_*(E))-ch(R^1(f_*E))= ch^{(1)}(E)-(g-1)ch^{(0)}(E)$$ where $ch^{(0)}$ and $ch^{(1)}$ are such as $$ch(E)=ch^{(0)}(E)+ch^{(1/2)}(E)+ch^{(1)}(E)$$ with $c^{(i)}(E) \in H^{2i}(C) \otimes H^*(Y)$ thank to Kunneth decomposition. But I don't know hot to deduce that expression for  $c_1(\pi_*(U))$ from GRR